# Jquery eq() use column name instead of index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `jQuery` to get the 5th column text in a table and change the text of a textbox

```
$('textbox').val($(e.target).closest("tr").find('td:eq(4)').text());
```

However, lets say another developer moved the index of the columns (Yes I could comment to say don't move around or use the correct index, but I guess this is the lazy way) then it would incorrectly select the wrong column's text. So how could I change `eq(index)` to use a static column name instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the cell a class, then select by class:

```
$('textbox').val($(e.target).closest("tr").find('td.myClass').text());
```

Or to use the attribute you mentioned in comments:

```
$('textbox').val($(e.target).closest("tr").find('td[aria-describedby="yourValue"]').text());
```

Comment: This looks good, however, instead of `class` can I use another attribute such as `aria-describedby` (this is a `jqGrid` so it populates the HTML for me)

Comment: @user3428422 Check my update, I've added a version that uses `aria-describedby`

Comment: this is awesome, thanks, will accept once SO lets me

Comment: @user3428422 No probs, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that would not depend on any specific implementation like `jqGrid` would be to keep an array with the column names like:

```
var columnNames = [];

$('table').find('th').each (function () {
   columnNames.push($(this).text().trim());
});
```

Then you can get an index of a column with a O(1) operation:

```
var index = columnNames.indexOf("Inv No");
```

And you can use that index in your existing expression:

```
$('textbox').val($(e.target).closest("tr").find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text());
```

This would give you the flexibility to switch to another table/grid plugin without changing the code!

Here is an example applied to HTML rendered by jqGrid:

http://jsfiddle.net/fukt548f/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
this may help you
$('textbox').val($(e.target).closest("tr").children().eq(4).text());
```

Comment: The question was "So how could I change eq(index) to use a static column name instead?" This is just another syntax for the same query, the author provided